# Where should I put toast statement in the try statement after finish()?

Tags: android, try-catch, toast

I am facing error when doing toast statement in a try statement. Here is my code. Currently put a toast statement in this way (commented format). May I know what is the correct way of putting? Thanks.

```
try {
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs2));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    final String response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
    System.out.println("Response : " + response1); 
    if(response1.contains("Duplicated")){
        finish();
    }
    //{Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have registered this event before.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    {
        jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    }

    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is *not* recommended?

Comment: "I am facing error" -- [use LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) to examine the Java stack trace associated with your error. Also, using a `Toast` for an error condition ("have not registered this event") is not a good idea, as the user may be distracted and not see the `Toast`. You should consider using something else, like [a crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton), that can stay around a while.

Comment: You need to correct two things. **1** `catch block` should be written `immediately after try block` always. **2** you should display `Toast before you write finish()`

Comment: use your activityName.this like---> Toast.makeText(activityName.this, "You have registered this event before.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Comment: It's rather Java related question than Android one. Where to put your toast really depends on what you want to achieve. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: @jimmeng3395: is it the code inside `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I have fixed it myself.

```
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs2));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response1); 
        if(response1.contains("Duplicated")){

            Register.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "You have registered this event before.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            finish();
        }
        jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    }

    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```